# Change a SQL Server 2008 R2 database collation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a database and I forgot to set its collation. So all my chars are like `????` in it. The default one is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and I want to change it to `Persian_100_CI_AS`.

I used this SQL statement:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE land_gis
COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS ;
GO
```

But I get this `error` :

```
Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1  
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.

Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'land_gis' cannot be 
 set to Persian_100_CI_AS.
```

I can not `drop` and rebuild database. Is there any way to change it?

Thanks a lot

By the way, I'm using *SQL Server 2008 R2*.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your database is in use - if you're **confident** that you'll do no harm - you can use this code to get exclusive access:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE land_gis
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO 

ALTER DATABASE land_gis
COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS ;
GO
```

Then your `ALTER DATABASE COLLATE` call should work .

**WARNING:** this call to `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` will disconnect anyone who might be connected to that database without warning, without chance of saving data! **USE WITH CAUTION!** especially in production environments!!

Comment: Thanks my friend.I used your code but got this error:Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The object 'spatial_ref_xyunits' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.

Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'land_gis' cannot be set to Persian_100_CI_AS.

Comment: Is there any way to copy this database with a new collation?I don't have any records but The database itself is important :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_lock` then find the `spid` associated with concerned DB and kill them (but first you can check them whats running behind them by

```
DBCC inputbuffer(spid))


USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE land_gis
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO 

ALTER DATABASE land_gis
COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS ;
GO
```